# How to Add Footnotes Under Paragraphs, Princess Bride Style?

Tags: footnotes, paragraphs, marginnote, sidenotes, parnotes

In the book, "Princess Bride", (Yeah, the book is SO much better than the movie.), the author has running commentary which is directly below the paragraph that it is associated to.  How could this be done in LaTeX to look like that, (perhaps with `\parnotes` package or maybe some other insidious way?)

```
There is a box of things that I put nothing in \ParagraphNote{Perhaps related 
to a particular cat, but it is neither here nor there.}, but sometimes the 
lid is open so things can't fall out.   I wonder where this story is going\ldots

Footnotes should go here.

Another paragraph would start, on the same page.\ParagraphNote{with
more content of course.}

And more footnotes would go below that paragraph.**
```

`\parnotes` is kinda close, but what would the "Princess Bride" formatting look like with those hooks?

In the MSS that I am editing, there are several hundred pages, but no `\par` tags or environments are used.

Comment: The `footnote` package has a `savenotes` environment that displays all footnotes at the end of the environment, instead of the bottom of the page. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: It would help if you provided a visual example of what “*the "Princess Bride" formatting*” looks like